Flow Reminder Emails 30 days away, 15 days away...?
I have a use case where a director is requesting reminder emails to be sent per the following criteria within an Opportunity;

When a Proposal Due Date (custom date field) is 30 days away and there is no TBR Date (custom date field) value.

When a Proposal Due Date (custom date field) is 15 days away and there is no TBR Date (custom date field) value.

When a Proposal Due Date (custom date field) is 7 days away and there is no TBR Date (custom date field) value.


How would I build this?? I imagine the flow would need to probably run every day and check the Proposal Due Date value within that opportunity and compare it with the current system date and when it hits the 30 days away mark and there's no TBR Date, BOOM send an email to x x...then run again every day to see if it hits a 15 day mark etc etc??

I imagine the flow would need to probably run every day and check the Proposal Due Date value within that opportunity and compare it with the current system date  - sounds like a good option, give it a shot.

You can use a Record-Triggered Flow with Scheduled Paths. Make the entry condition for the flow something like Proposal Due Date Is Blank False AND TBR Date Is Blank True. Next, create three paths that trigger 30, 15, and 7 days before Proposal Due Date, and add an email or task action (or both). You will need to update existing records once before they'll be scheduled, but all future records will automatically enroll in the reminders, and also cancel the reminders if the record is subsequently edited to no longer meet the criteria (e.g. TBR Date becomes populated).

Thank you for the response sfdcfox! So I created that exact setup and I set it to 1 days before, 2 days before and 3 days before for testing...I set the Proposal Due Date to 7/10/2024 and triggered the flow...it skipped day 1 and sent me the reminder for 2 days before and 3 days before meaning it didn't stop at the 1 day before scheduled path and just skipped it...any idea what I did wrong?

@DmitriyGerchikov It did as I would expect. Three days before July 10th is July 7th, but today's the 8th, so it sent you the 3 days before message, the 2 days before message, and paused to wait until tomorrow, July 9th, to send the last email.

Quick follow up, is there a way to make it so if the Proposal Due Date is set below a 30 day mark or 14 day mark, to disregard the two scheduled paths and not send the emails?

@DmitriyGerchikov You can add a decision to see if there's fewer days left than when the path executes. Start with a formula like {!$Record.Proposal_Date__c}-TODAY(), then add a Decision to check if {!RemainingDays} Less Than 15 (for example), and if so, then skip sending the email.

@DmitriyGerchikov Just remember that - calculates the days between two dates, so the check for 30 days would need to check for 29 instead.

Awesome!! So if I was to create a formula to use to check if the Proposal Due Date value is greater than 30 days, what would that look like?? I'm not proficient with formula's at all :( I need to change that it's a powerful tool to know!
